# How to configure CakePHP in Travis-Ci

Tags: php, cakephp, travis-ci, cakephp-2.3

I have a CakePHP project where I also integrated Travis-CI to start automated testing. 
Now my tests look something like this:

```
<?php 
    App::uses('CustomControllerTest', 'Lib');
    class AllocationsControllerTest extends CustomControllerTest
{...
```

My travis.yml:

```
language: php
php:
  - '5.3'

before_script:
  - composer install
  - php bootstrap.php

script:
  phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --coverage-text
```

`bootsrap.php` is currently empty.

When triggering Travis it says it doesn't find Class'App'.
What do I have to add to the `.travis.yml` or `bootstrap.php` so it loads all the dependencies needed in the test classes?

Comment: Why not looking into existing projects to find out? See the awesome list for available ones, e.g. https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-sandbox/blob/3.0/.travis.yml